# How to read multiple text files from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file

I currently have code to read one specific file in Java but I am wanting to read file names from an array in Java.

For example, I have an array of file names e.g.

```
String[] files = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "File3.txt"};
```

I want to be able to open the file in an array when a user clicks a button and when they click button again, it opens next file etc.

Can you please kindly show me how to do this?

Stripped down code:

```
public void loadFile(String fileName) {
    InputStreamReader myReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(files[0]));
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(myReader);

}
```

Comment: One file at a time?

Comment: Can you share the code that you already have?

Comment: Yes, as default file1.txt should open then using a button, file1.txt closes and file2.txt should open and button, file2.txt closes and file3.txt opens instead etc

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that we can copy-paste, compile and run without any modification, as a tip for doing what you're trying to do: 1) Create your GUI 2) Create a variable `current` that will "remember" which index of the array of files you've read already 3) On every button click call your `loadFile` and pass as a parameter `files[current]` 4) Do whatever you need to do with it 5) Remember that it may throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you reach the end of the array 6) Success!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically

```java
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   InputStreamReader myReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(files[i]));
   BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(myReader);
}
```